# Python Starting Code after the function is finished

Tags: python

I'm working on interactive method with matplotlib.

I want to proceed my code after finishing the plotting

but in pycharm, it is hard to achieve.

is there any way to control it?

(I want to work it as a jupyternotebook's cell)

```
def Coordinates(input): # input is the image data 
    plt.ion() 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
    ax.imshow(input) 
    line = ax.scatter(xy[1], xy[0], c='red', s=3, picker=5) 
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onpick) 
    plt.ioff() 
    return line 

line = Coordinates(input) 
New = line.get_offsets() 
New_input = New.data
```

Comment: Please be more specific, at least find some somall example somewhere that does about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: if I write the pseudo code it's like this


def Coordinates(input): # input is the image data
...
...

    plt.ion()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(input)
    line = ax.scatter(xy[1], xy[0], c='red', s=3, picker=5)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onpick)
    plt.ioff()
    return line

line = Coordinates(input)
New = line.get_offsets()
New_input = New.data


I want to get the object 'line' after revising the scatter plot, but when I run it, the New.data is executed before I'm finished with fixing the scatter plot.

Comment: Please modify your question and add the code there.

Comment: I modified the code, so can you please help??

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

plt.show()

while True:
    print('finished')
    time.sleep(1)
```